# How to intersect multiple sets?

Tags: java, set, intersection

I have this list:

```
private List<Set<Address>> scanList;
```

So my list contains multiple scans as you can see.
After each scan I add new set into the list.

After all scans are finished I would like to take only the addresses that occur in every set and put it into:

```
private List<Address> addresses;
```

Does something like this already exists in Set/TreeSet/HashSet?

EDIT: after answers, retainAll() is the right method. Thank you.
Here is the source:

```
Set<Address> addressCross = scanList.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < scanList.size(); i++) {
    addressCross.retainAll(scanList.get(i));
}   
for (Address address : addressCross) {
    addresses.add(address);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See "retainAll()".

Answer (score 16):

you can use `retainAll(Collection<?> c)`, check it out [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

A side note: that operation is called **intersection**.

To convert then it to a `List` you can use the method `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` which should work between all kinds of containers.

eg:

```
ArrayList<Address> list = new ArrayList<Address>();
list.addAll(yourSet);
```

Answer (score 8):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/), you could do it like this:

```
Set<Address> intersection = scanList.get(0);
for (Set<Address> scan : scanList.subList(1, scanList.size())) {
  intersection = Sets.intersection(intersection, scan);
}
List<Address> addresses = Lists.newArrayList(intersection);
```

This creates a view of the intersection of all the sets in the `scanList` and then copies the addresses in the intersection into a `List`. You would need to ensure your `scanList` has at least one element in it, of course.

Comment: Beware! According to Louis Wasserman, `Sets.union()` has poor performance for more than 2 sets. I believe the same holds true for `Sets.intersection()` (because both methods return views).

Comment: @Gili: This is generally true, though it's mitigated by the fact that the intersection set is copied at the end, which means that the cost of the nested sets is only incurred there. The issue of nested view sets is bigger if you then pass the set off to some other code that may do many `contains` calls on it.

Comment: I've come to this discussion a bit late but doesn't this solution assume the first set contains the "key" elements. For example consider the first set with integers (11,12), the 2nd with (1,3,4,5,6), and so. When I code this up the final multi-intersection set is empty!

Comment: @user25029: The goal is to create a list containing only those elements that appear in _all_ sets. So if there is any pair of sets in the input that do not contain any of the same elements (i.e. their intersection is empty), the final result must be empty.

Answer (score 0):

There's another nice solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266681/349169

```
Set<Address> intersection = scanList.stream()
    .skip(1) // optional
    .collect(()->new HashSet<>(scanList.get(0)), Set::retainAll, Set::retainAll);
```